# Verify routing via PDUR

Tags: autosar

In order to verify if a message is received in the COM layer, we can add a Ipdu callout for the Pdu/Signal and wait for the breakpoint to be hit while debugging.

This is not the case for Pdu routing.

If a message is routed via the PduR , it never goes to the Com Layer.
Hence there is no possibility to verify if the message is received by the device(i.e PduR has no callout functionality).

Is there a way where we can verify if the message is received by PduR, and is successfully copied to a Tx Pdu to be sent out(i.e Verify successful gatewaying)?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that PduR can sometimes have multiple destinations, we have such ECUs, that are routing messages e.g. locally to Com and at the same time, route them to transmit on a different network.

The PduR is triggered by RxIndications and TxConfirmations (and their Tp-interface counterparts).
So, for a normal routing relationship, you should hook on RxIndication for a RxPdu, and could e.g. wait for a TxConfirmation of the TxPdu, which tells, that the TxPdu was transmitted.

Keep in mind, that:

- a RxPdu could be queued, which means, they will  maybe not directly be transmitted. This might be handy in case of streaming Pdus like XCP, in order to keep the ordering of the PDUs if they can currently not be transmitted.
- Routing Paths might be enabled/disabled at runtime, e.g. system conditions handled by BswM Rules and ActionLists calling `PduR_[Enable|Disable]Routing(<routingpathgroupId>)`